# How is Prettier Code Formatter different from the default code formatter in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I want to use a code formatter to properly format my code. There a default formatter available in VSCode. I want to know how 'Prettier' is different from that default formatters.

Answer (score 3):

Prettier works consistently accross different IDEs and lets you configure the code formatting rules at your repository level. Which can then be used by all developers working on that repository, without a need to change thier IDE settings again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prettier code formatter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) in vs code to make your code prettier